# Access to ngSanitize in child components

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I am trying to use `ng-bind-html` in a child component and it is not working. From what I read, You need to include ngSanitize. Which I have on am parent component and works fine there but can't get it to work on the child. Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

```
var myApp = angular.module('subPackages', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages','ngSanitize']).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
      // Allow same origin resource loads.
      'self',
      // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
      '<<Protected Content>>**'
    ]);
});



(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.component('appComponent', {
        templateUrl: '../subpackages/templates/app-template.html',
        controller: subAppController
    });

    app.component('cartSummary', {
        templateUrl: '../subpackages/templates/cart-summary.template.html',
        controller: cartSummaryController,
        bindings: {
            contentJson: '<',
            cartPerfs: '<',
            getGlobalContent: '&',
            myNewHtml: '&',
            callExecLocalProd: '&'

        },
    });


})(myApp);
```

Parent

```
function subAppController($sce, $compile) {
...
}
```

Child

```
function cartSummaryController($sce, $compile) {

    this.$onInit = function () {


        //Get content from Parent
        this.globalContent = this.getGlobalContent;
        this.cartSummary = this.cartPerfs;
        this.myHtml = this.myNewHtml;
        this.localProd = this.callExecLocalProd;

        this.removePerf = function (obj) {
            console.log("removing performance");
            var liseqno = $("#mBtnRemove").data("liseqno");
            var perfno = $("#mBtnRemove").data("perfno");

            //Close modal
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

            var rpParam = [
                { elp_remove_li_seq_no: liseqno, elp_remove_perf_no: perfno }
            ]

            this.localProd({ item: rpParam });
        }

    }; //End $onInit

    this.confirmDelete = function (perf) {
        console.log("Confirm Delete");
        console.log(perf);



        //Replace the perf_desc token with perf description
        var msg = this.globalContent({ module: "subpackage", item: "modalMessage" });
        var finalDesc = msg.replace(/{perf_desc}/g, perf.perf_desc);

        //Set the body of the modal with our message
        //$('.modal-body ').text($sce.trustAsHtml(finalDesc));
        //$('.cs-modal-body').attr("ng-bind-html", $sce.trustAsHtml(finalDesc));
        $('.cs-modal-body').attr("ng-bind-html", finalDesc);


        //populate our data attributes that we will need later
        $('#mBtnRemove').data("liseqno", perf.li_seq_no)
        $('#mBtnRemove').data("perfno", perf.perf_no)
        $('#myModal').modal();

    }

}
```

In my html I am using

```
<p class="cs-modal-body" ng-bind-html="Here"></p>
```

Comment: when you say it is not working, is it showing any error ?

Comment: No error. Just nothing displays. This is the element I am trying with.

Comment: <p class="cs-modal-body" ng-bind-html="Here"></p>

Comment: is here defined in your controller ? show your view and complete code (relevant parts)

Comment: also which angular version are you using ?

Comment: No it isn't. I was just trying plain text to try to narrow down the issue. I am trying to populate ng-bind-html from the background.  I will add the entire child controller in a second.

Comment: if you use  ng-bind-html="Here", then "Here" should be defined somewhere in your scope/context - it should be a string, which angular will try to parse as html

Comment: I am using Angular 1.6.2

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Binding it to the controller worked. If you post that as the answer, I will accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `ng-bind-html="Here"`, then "Here" should be defined somewhere in your scope/context - it should be a string, which angular will try to parse as html

Define it in the controller.